# Display next button within bootstrap after correct survey answer

Tags: javascript, function, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a quiz form that will identify if the answer is correct or incorrect via text. I am looking to display a NEXT button if correct but not sure how to entire the html into the function - currently it's this...

```
 $.fn.checking = function(ck) {
    if (ck != $ans)
        return 'INCORRECT';
    else 
        return 'CORRECT!';
};
```

Comment: usually when you need to append some element into html - you could use code lie this: $('#your-form-id').append('<button>next</button>') , hope it helps...

Comment: So I would add this after the else return ' $('#your-form-id').append('<button>next</button>')'

Comment: Another way would be to show hide the next button. You can do this by adding and removing "disabled" class when $checking(ck) === "CORRECt!".

Comment: I'm confused... based on the code I have I need to have a ELSE return a button instead of text while leaving the incorrect as is (text). The goal is if the user answers the question correctly a next step BUTTON appears. I have button styles already just trying how to input the HTML about the ELSE RETURN in JS

Comment: Essentially what I am hoping to accomplish is using checkboxes based on this template https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-quiz-with-radio-button when an answer is selected the checkbox will be active. If INCORRECT the text message is revealed. If CORRECT a next button is revealed to move on to the next quiz.